# How to create dynamic log4net settings

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I'm trying to create dynamic settings for log4net.
I need to send logs for different instances, but I don't know their number.
Is it possible to create all this in C# code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
hierarchy.Root.RemoveAllAppenders(); /*Remove any other appenders*/

foreach (var appender in GetAppenders())
{
   hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(appender);
}

hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Info;
hierarchy.Configured = true;
```

Where `GetAppenders` returns a collection of the `IAppender` you needed.